# How to convert iOS Device Token String back to NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I'm sure this question has been asked before but for the life of me I cannot find the right answer.

In Objective-C you have this:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken;
```

Which is great, the deviceToken isn't a string, so usually you convert that to a string and send that along to methods that require the NSData (Exact target example:

```
[[ETPush pushManager] registerDeviceToken:deviceToken];
```

That all works great :)

The problem is, in my setup I'm calling that method from *outside* the original deviceToken function, so I actually have access to the token as a string already. So what I need to do is turn that string *back* into the deviceToken NSData object. I can do this to turn it to an NSData object:

```
NSData *deviceToken = [stringToken dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

But the problem there is that then when I look at the description I get something like:

```
<63333833 30613765 ... 64386561 30653861 61356164 31353338 35623665 34396563>
```

If you look at every single implementation of the question, *How do I convert an NSData Device Token to NSString?* they answer with something like this (or something similar using bytes):

```
NSString * deviceTokenString = [[[[deviceToken description]
                     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""] 
                    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""] 
                   stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
```

As you can imagine, take that string above that I posted and use it in that method and it creates something like:

```
6333383330613765....etc.
```

Which is clearly not my device token :)

So the question!

**How do I convert it back to an NSData object that I can send to those methods?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it! I was able to do this using this extremely helpful link:

http://iphoneappcode.blogspot.com/2012/04/nsdata-to-hexstring-and-hexstring-to.html

```
- (NSData *)dataFromHexString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSMutableData *stringData = [[[NSMutableData alloc] init] autorelease];
    unsigned char whole_byte;
    char byte_chars[3] = {'\0','\0','\0'};
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < [string length] / 2; i++) {
        byte_chars[0] = [string characterAtIndex:i*2];
        byte_chars[1] = [string characterAtIndex:i*2+1];
        whole_byte = strtol(byte_chars, NULL, 16);
        [stringData appendBytes:&whole_byte length:1];
    }
    return stringData;
}
```

And then:

```
NSData *deviceToken = [self dataFromHexString:myStringToken];
```

:)

Comment: Works for me! It's really help you to work with `deviceToken` if you save it like a `string` and after need to take form it `NSData`. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I've looked for!